# ReactNative - Font colour not working with Samsung Devices alone

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have return a code in reactnative app with assigned font colour as black. Which working fine with app with other mobile Devices other than Samsung Devices.

Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Can you paste the code how you style  the text?
Maybe you need en-US -> color: '#ff0000' instead of colour.

Comment: export const COLORS = {
  // black: '#1E1F20',
  primary: '#ba1c1c',
  primary_light: '#f6f6fb',
  orange: '#eca4a4',
  orange_light: '#f7eaeb',
  orange_grey: '#f7f0f0',
  violet: '#6d42f9',
  light: '#ffff',
  black: '#000000',
  primary_shade: '#F1959B',
  primary_shade_light: '#fad9db',
  neon_green: '#39ff14',
  grey_silver: '#C0C0C0',
  grey: '#808080',
  dark_blue: '#6b61e2',
  light_container: '#FAFAFA',
  light_countdown: '#e3e1dc',
  green:"#04B404",
};

Comment: the color you expect is black, then what the color you see in Samsung Devices?

Comment: And how you apply the style?

Comment: Can you please update you question with ALL the code in question, what you expect to see, what you actually see, which android devices show the color correctly, which android devices don't, and whether they are physical or sims?